# Phaser javaScript game framework , function is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I am using the phaser Javascript framework to make a simple game. My player object is assigned different states, e.g: `onground`, `inair`, etc

I am trying to assign a method to this.currentState. In the update loop, I am  calling `this.currentState` to run the assigned method (`this.groundState`).

However, I am receiving the following error -

> 'this.currentState is not a function'

Can anyone help?

```
SuperSmash.Player = function(game, x, y) {
    Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, x, y, 'player');

    this.game.physics.arcade.enable(this);
    this.speed = 500;
    this.airSpeed = 300;

    this.currentState = this.groundState; 
    console.log(this.currentState); // undefined 
};

SuperSmash.Player.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
SuperSmash.Player.prototype.constructor = SuperSmash.Player;

SuperSmash.Player.prototype.update = function() {
    this.currentState();
};

SuperSmash.Player.prototype.groundState = function() {
    console.log('ground');
};
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. If I run the exact same code you posted, the function is there and I can even call it.

Comment: How are you calling the constructor? BTW it should be `console.log(this.currentState());`